# how to make an element not expanding the margin of others

Tags: css

I have a form, and each time an input gets focus there's this hint showing and telling the user what should be done ("specify an 8 digits password" and so on).

the problem is, everytime it appears, because of the size, the input's margin gets bigger or smaller (depends on the hint's size). i want the inputs the remain where they are and not get further from each other every time.

this is the css part of the hints (which marked as `p` elements).

```
p {
margin: 0px 0 0 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border: 2px solid #5cb85c;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 3px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
color: white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
width: 350px;
text-align: center;}
```

I couldn't think of more necessary parts of codes to post, let me know if you need them.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

my html:

```
 <table class="innertable">
    <tr>
      <td width="200px">
                                            Character Name:
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Firstname_Lastname" class="form-control" class="col-md-3" value="">

     </td>
     <td>
     <p id="nameHint" class="hint">Please specify a username using A-Z letters only, in a Firstname_Lastname format</p>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
                                            Password:
    </td>
    <td>
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
    <p id="passHint" class="hint">Please specify an 8 digits password</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
                                        Verify Password:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="password" name="password_verify" id="password_verify" class="form-control" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <p id="verifyHint" class="hint">Please specify your password again, for verification</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Age:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" value="">                                 
   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to leave enough space for hints to appear, or make hint as position:absolute; and z-index:10 (anything higher than 1 would do) and position it near the relevant input. 
Without seeing your HTML I can't give any better advice.

Now that I saw your HTML, I believe you can solve it by setting manually the  width for the input column:

```
<td width="200px">
    <input type ...
</td>
```

Comment: and i'm using bootstrap (unfortunately the team demands..)

I must thank you for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

`box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:relative;` to table, and `position:absolute;` to p element. That is making p relative to table. So you could use `top, left, right, bottom` properties to eyeball it. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v62rbdLz/

Code:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
}
#nameHint {
  top: 0px;
}
#passHint {
  top: 50px;
}
#verifyHint {
  top: 80px;
}
```

Now you should be careful and double check values so layout would not brake.